# Adding Constraint to entity referenced Paragraph field

Tags: 8, forms, plugins

I'm attempting to follow [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) to add a custom constraint to a field in a Paragraph but I'm having trouble in adding constraint to that field.

Currently I have `book` content type  with paragraph type `bibliographic_information`. This paragraph type has a field named as `field_book_edition`. This field accepts a string value. I'd like to be able to add a constraint to the field so that it accepts a certain string pattern as input.

I've created constrain and tried using `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`, when ever I try to save the node I am getting the following error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

> InvalidArgumentException: Field field_bibliographic_information is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

My Code is as follows :

**book_content.module**

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter().
 */
function book_content_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {

  // Refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/277438/

  if ($entity_type->id() === 'paragraph' && $bundle === 'bibliographic_information' && isset($fields['field_book_edition'])) {

    // Add our custom validation to the book edition field.
    $fields['field_book_edition']->addConstraint('BookContentEditionConstraint');
  }

}
```

**BookContentEditionConstraintValidator.php**

```
namespace Drupal\book_content\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the Book Content constraint.
 */
class BookContentEditionConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint) {

    $node = $entity->getEntity();

    // Get referenced paragraph entities.
    $referenceItem = $node->get('field_bibliographic_information')->referencedEntities();

    foreach ($referenceItem as $data) {

      $fields = [
        'field_book_author' => $data->field_book_price->value,
        'field_book_edition'  => $data->field_book_edition->value,
        'field_book_language'  => $data->field_book_language->value,
        'field_book_pages'  => $data->field_book_pages->value,
        'field_book_price'  => $data->field_book_price->value,
        'field_book_published_year'  => $data->field_book_published_year->value,
        'field_book_synopsis'  => $data->field_book_synopsis->value,
        'field_website'  => $data->field_website->getValue()[0]['uri'],
      ];
    }

    // Check if the book edition matches or not.
    if ($fields['field_book_edition'] != 'asdfg') {

      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidEdition, ['@edition' => $fields['field_book_edition']]);
    }

  }

}
```

Attached the Node and Paragraph structures screenshot.

I have gone through similar questions and read their comments/answers but coundn't find what exactly is the error in the code.

[Add Constraint to Paragraph Field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/277438/)  answer by [Carlos](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/76650/carlos)

[Adding Constraint to Paragraph field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278067/adding-constraint-to-paragraph-field?rq=1#comment345690_278087) comment by [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4)

I implemented the same what is mentioned in both the links.But still it is not working.

For debugging purpose I have added the above constraint to a node field and it worked as expected.

From what I read if you provide the correct `$entity_type->id()` all the fields for the particular entity id will be rendered in `$fields` variable in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` , is my understanding is correct ?

Should I be implementing `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` or `hook_form_alter` for adding a
custom constraint to a paragraph field ?

[image: Paragraph Structure]
[image: Node Structure]

**EDIT 1:**

After further debugging if I add

```
if ($node->hasField('field_bibliographic_information')) {
   \Drupal::logger('book_content')->info('Hello');
 $referenceItem = $node->get('field_bibliographic_information')->referencedEntities();
 ....remaining code.....
 }
```

in `validate` method the code inside the loop doesn't get executed.

Comment: Your constraint is receiving an entity, then you need to add it to the entity type, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224229/validate-a-custom-type-node-before-submitting

Comment: Hi @4k4 thank you for your response. Are you referring to use hook_entity_type_alter ? If so isnt it is for whole entity type and not for a specific field in entity type ? Can you please elaborate what you re referring to ?

Comment: A constraint with `validate($entity)`  has to be attached to an entity, not a field. Besides from being an entity or field constraint you attach it to a paragraph and then expect that it has a node field.

Comment: Hi @4k4 I am completely lost can you please share a code snippet or any reference contrib module so that I can have a look. I also added additional debug info to the question, can you please have a look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to achieve this finally.

Basically what I was doing wrong was I was assuming the $entity is a node object and but it actually is paragraph object.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\book_content\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;


/**
 * Validates the Book Content constraint.
 */
class BookContentEditionConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {

    if (!$item = $items->first()) {
      return;
    }

    $field_name = $items->getFieldDefinition()->getName();

    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity */
    $entity = $items->getEntity();

    if ($entity->hasField('field_book_edition')) {

      $edition = $entity->field_book_edition->value;


      // Check if the book edition matches or not.
      if ($edition != 'asdfg') {

        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidEdition, ['@edition' => $edition]);
      }

    }

  }

}
```