# How do I validate an entity before programmatically saving it?

Tags: 8, entities

I have various functions/methods that programmatically create entities (nodes). I just noticed that invalid data has been getting stored in the db though these functions (invalid in that it doesn't meet the rules defined for that field).

How do I validate the data before $entity->save()?

I have seen documentation saying that I simply need to do $entity->validate() and then count if there are any errors; but I have marked a few fields as required and then left them empty in my API function and $entity->validate()->count() is always 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to create field constraints refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294733/adding-constraint-to-entity-referenced-paragraph-field

Comment: @miststudent2011, thanks for the reply, but that post sounds a lot like how to add custom constraints. I do not have any custom constraints I want to add; I just want to validate against the existing ones. That being said, I am starting to get the idea that the constraints which fields do by default are only designed for form submission and not as "proper" constraints. Is this possible; and if so, wouldn't this be considered a bug in core?

Answer (score 4):

[Looking the api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview#s-using-the-api) it should be simple:

```
$violations = $entity->validate();
  if ($violations->count() > 0) {
    // Validation failed.
  }
```

Comment: Yes, should be simple enough. Except that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to debug inside the validation function when you call it, to see where the logic doesn't work?